# Option Compare Text in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, directive, case-insensitive

This should be a no-brainer, but I haven't really written any classic ASP code in like 10 years and just cannot remember how to do this, and can't find it on google.

All I'm looking to do is to set a Classic ASP page to use Option Compare Text, but I cannot remember the syntax for this. I've tried all of the following, as the first lines in my file...

```
<%Option Compare Text%>
<%Option Compare="Text"%>
<%Option=CompareText%>
<%Compare="Text"%>
<%Option="Compare Text"%>
<%@Option Compare Text%>
<%@Option Compare="Text"%>
```

I'm pretty sure it is something with the @ symbol like the last two, but just can't remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Option Compare` in VBScript, sorry.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30593abb%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Could you not use `StrComp` function that has parameter for the method of comparison?

Comment: Well, I was trying to use the Replace function to do some keyword highlighting in a set of search results. I wound up instead using the RegExp object and using its Replace method. I'm still curious though if anyone can answer how to do this...